# Slient Maria DB Install is not working

Tags: mariadb

I am using the following commands for the silent installation of Maria DB on ubuntu 14.04.

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mariadb-server-10.0 mysql-server/root_password password PASS'
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mariadb-server-10.0 mysql-server/root_password_again password PASS'
sudo apt-get install -y mariadb-server
```

But it always prompt the following content in a window

```
   ────────────────────┤ Configuring mariadb-server-5.5 ├────────────────────┐
  │                                                                          │
  │ MariaDB is a drop-in replacement for MySQL. It will use your current     │
  │ configuration file (my.cnf) and current databases.                       │
  │                                                                          │
  │ Note that MariaDB has some enhanced features, which do not exist in      │
  │ MySQL and thus migration back to MySQL might not always work, at least   │
  │ not as automatically as migrating from MySQL to MariaDB.                 │
  │                                                                          │
  │ Really migrate to MariaDB?                                               │
  │                                                                          │
  │                    

                   [Yes]                       [No]                      │
```

Could anyone help me in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I was trying to create a provision script for vagrant to install and configure MariaDB, to solve the problem I set the variable **DEBIAN_FRONTEND** to **noninteractive** and used sudo's -E option [1] to load all existing variables:

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
sudo -E apt-get install -y mariadb-server
```

[1]

> -E, --preserve-env
>
> Indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to preserve their existing environment variables.  The security policy may return
>   an error if the user does not have permission to preserve the
>   environment.